# How to stop an infinite kill command loop in a realm server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I accidentally started a kill loop that kills everyone on the realm. How do I stop this on a realm?

Comment: Why you start a kill loop like that, I don't know

Comment: Can't you just turn off the config option that enables command blocks?

Comment: This post should be re-opened because it's not a duplicate

Answer (score 4):

### There is a way to fix it!

1. Download a backup of the realm
2. Get MCEdit(if you don't have it already)
3. Use MCEdit and find the command block kill loop
4. Destroy it ( replace it with other blocks )
5. Save MCEdit
6. Open realms
7. Realm settings
8. Upload your fixed world
9. There you go! Your realms world is now fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Disable command blocks, log in and break the block, re-enable command blocks. You have to be an admin of the realms server.

In minecraft:

- Click Minecraft Realms.
- Click configure (the wrench)
- Click World Options
- Click "Command Blocks: On" to change it to "Command Blocks: Off"
- Log in, remove block
- Repeat previous steps to re-enable command blocks